# Bind multiple files to array with properties

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a basic `HTML` form with `<input type="file" multiple>` inside. For each chosen file I create a description.

Now I want to bind them to `PostedPhotoViewModel[] PostedPhotos;`:

```
public abstract class PostedPhotoViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how to prepare my input to do such a thing. Is it possible? Or do I have to do some tricks to achieve my target?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostedPhotos, new { @name = "PostedPhotos", type = "file", multiple="multiple" })
```

I tried to force it in such a way, but didn't work:

```
myForm.submit(function(e) {
    myInput.files = $.map(myInput.files, function(element) {
        return {File: element, Description: "Test description"}
    });
    return true;
});
```

It's basic `ASP.NET MVC 5` project.

Comment: What is `PostedPhotos` (your model does not include a property with that name) And what is the model in the view? And how do you create the input for the `Description`?

Comment: It is a property in my model `public PostedPhotoViewModel[] PostedPhotos {get; set;}`

Comment: But that property is a collection. You cannot bind an input (or any form element) to a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostedPhotos, new { @name = "PostedPhotos", type = "file", multiple="multiple" })
```

With just:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
```

Then in the controller do something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

I think the nested view model list binding with a textbox property is making it far more complicated than it is.